# how to define a CAPL function taking a sysvar argument

Tags: capl, canoe

In Vector CANoe, is it possible to define a function that takes a system variable argument like the system function `TestWaitForSignalMatch()`?

For my use case it is not sufficient to supply the current value of the system variable because I want to pass the system variable to `TestWaitForSignalMatch()` or similar system functions.

The CANoe help seems to show examples:

```
long TestWaitForSignalMatch (Signal aSignal, float aCompareValue, dword aTimeout); // form 1
long TestWaitForSignalMatch (sysvar aSysVar, float aCompareValue, dword aTimeout); // form 3
```

I tried like this

```
void foo(sysvar aSysvar) {}
         ^
```

or this

```
void foo(sysvar *aSysvar) {}
         ^
```

but I get a parse error at the marked position of the `sysvar` keyword in both cases.

I successfully created functions that take a signal argument, but unlike the syntax in the CANoe help I have to use a pointer.
This works:

```
void foo(signal *aSignal) {}
```

Obviously the documentation in the help is not correct in this point. It results in a parse error after the `signal` keyword when I omit the `*` as shown in the help:

```
void bar(signal aSignal) {}
               ^
```

So what's the correct syntax for defining a function that takes a sysvar argument? (if possible)

In case the version matters, I'm currently testing with CANoe 9.0.53(SP1), 9.0.135(SP7) or 10.0.125(SP6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just define a bit further your sysvar type, not just sysvar.

> System variables, with indication of type and *.  Possible types:
>   Data, Int, Float, String, IntArray, and FloatArray. Example
>   declaration: sysvarFloat * sv

You didn't specify the CANoe SP version, so it may not be supported in older versions, but to make sure of this, search for **Function parameter** in Help/Index, then you should get the full list of possible function parameters you can use in your current CANoe setup. Should start like this:

- Integers (byte, word, dword, int, long, qword, int64) Example
  declaration: long 1
- Integers (byte, word, dword, int, long, qword, int64) Example
  declaration: long 1
- Individual characters (char) Example declaration: char ch
- Enums  Example declaration: enum Colors c
- Associative fields  Example declaration: int m[float]. Associative
  fields are transferred as reference automatically.

.............

- System variables, with indication of type and *.  Possible types:
  Data, Int, Float, String, IntArray, and FloatArray. Example
  declaration: sysvarFloat * sv

Comment: Thank you. I added the exact version numbers to my original question.
I successfully compiled a sample function using sysvarFloat* in CANoe 9.0.53(SP1).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the correct type. You have the following possibilities to declare system variables in functions:

- Integer: sysvarInt*
- Float: sysvarFloat*
- String: sysvarString*
- Integer Array: sysvarIntArray*
- Float Array: sysvarFloatArray*
- Data: sysvarData*

Examples:

```
void PutSysVarIntArrayToByteArray (sysvarIntArray * from, byte to[], word length)
{
  word ii;
  for (ii = 0; ii < length; ii++)
  {
    to[ii] = (byte)@from[ii];
  }
}
```

You can also write to the system variable:

```
void PutByteToSysVarInt (byte from, sysvarInt * to) {
  @to = from;
}
```

See also CANoe Help page "Test Features » XML » Declaration and Transfer of CAPL Test Case and Test Function Parameters"